# How to call a function within it while its an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

```
var scaleJssor = new Array();
for(myloop=0; myloop<jssor_slider.length; myloop++)
{
  scaleJssor.push(
        function() { 
             var parentWidth = jssor_slider[myloop].$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;

             if (parentWidth)
                {
                    //alert("executing ScaleSlider");
                    jssor_slider[myloop].$SetScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth-100, 960), 230));
                }
             else
                    window.setTimeout(<here I want to pass this function>, 30);

                });

}
```

The above is only a code snippet , I just want to know how can I pass the function within `setTimeout()` function where the function is anonymous, I know if I give a name to the function I can pass it easily, but I want a way by not giving any name to function.

Comment: Its not good practice to define functions within loops. It means function needs to be created in every iteration of loop. Better to define it outside of loop and then just call it in the loop.

Comment: I've found, personally, that I've started to shy away from anonymous functions.  When looking at console errors, its just nice to see the function name and have something to search for/jump to in the source code.  Anonymous functions are just a *touch* harder to debug.

Comment: @Craicerjack , I needed that loop because I was not defining a particular function , I am defining an array of functions.

Comment: Im not saying get rid of the loop. Im saying define the function outside of the loop and then push it into the array in the loop. That way you define the function once instead of on every iteration of the loop

Comment: Yes, I got your point. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: I have discarded the idea of loop and actually used it at the time of calling the function and as @user3817416 has suggested I have prefered passing dynamic arguement to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is not a good enough code because you are defining same function over and over in the loop. You should have defined the function outside the loop . I am just answering you for the question of setTimeout() function.
The following may do a good thing to work with if you pass a parameter to your function.

```
function ScaleJssor(k) { 
             var parentWidth = jssor_slider[k].$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;

             if (parentWidth)
                {
                    //alert("executing ScaleSlider");
                    jssor_slider[k].$SetScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth-100, 960), 230));
                }
             else
                    window.setTimeout(function(){ScaleJssor(k)}, 30);

                }
```

I think if you use the above code in your example you need not to use the loop anyway.

Comment: It is a perfect solution to my query . Thanks a lot mate. It has served my purpose and solved all my additional queries. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the next

```
someCode(function funcName() {
  // here you can access to function with funcName

});
```

this is works for next cases

```
var a = function b() {
  // here your function can be access with a or b
  // but 'b' garantee you that you call current function
  // and 'a' not - cause at code below you can redefine a-value to another one
  // also you can get function by 'b' outside function - it works only inside
}
```

Check it here http://jsbin.com/rakupayaxo/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply.So I got that at some point I have to give a name to the function to call it. Is it ?

Comment: Almost - when you  -- also you can get function by 'b' outside function - it works only inside -- check this comment. When you add name in such syntax - this name can be used only inside function - other code - can't use it

Answer (score 0):

Call function inside setTimeout.[check this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello");    }, 3000);
```

else

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
   myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
   alert("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to call the same function within it , which is surely possible while the function has a name , just like in your example I could have written myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 3000). But In my example it was an anonymous function. So I was wondered how could I get the same thing , how can I pass the anonymous function within that setTimeout() function. That's what my question .

Comment: Okay, `arguments.callee` is an option i think.Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxoxn6cg/7/).

Comment: Pls don't use `arguments.callee` its deprecated.check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050183/javascript-arguments-callee-what-is-it-for)

Comment: I have another question regarding this, will you please answer me? If I had a parameterized function, say I am passing an inetger value into the function and showing that value. So, in settimeout when I am calling the function how can I send parameter into that .
ex: 
`
function myFunction(n){
 alert(n);
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
}`

Now I want to pass an argument from setTimeout into myFunction. How can I accomplish that?