# onchange with alert not working in ie

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer, tags, onchange

javascript based tag ( `type ='file'` ) created

and add one attribute in that tag

that attribute name `onchange`, i will assign alert

**But alert is not come when choice the new file in internet explore.**

```
choicefile.setAttribute("onChange", "alert('test')");
```

Comment: Please give some code ,It not at all clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: Post your code. Easier to understand than words. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do two ways,

1.. Using HTML, add `onchange` event inline

```
<input type="file" id="file_select" name="file_select" value="" onchange="alert('File selected')" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CS3xJ/1/

2.. Using JS,

```
  choicefile.onchange = function(){
     alert('File selected')
  }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CS3xJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a difference between `setAttribute` and `attachEvent`. Here is an example using `attachEvent` (for IE) and `addEventListener` (standards) to add the event.

Also, not that the event handler is a function, rather than a string:

```
var eventHandler = function () {
    alert("Test");
}

if (choicefile.addEventListener) {
  choicefile.addEventListener('change', eventHandler , false);
} else if (choicefile.attachEvent)  {
  choicefile.attachEvent('onchange', eventHandler );
}
```

Comment: do bear in mind that `onchange` doesn't bubble in IE on select elements. To delegate an onchange event you'll need [a rather lengthy workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331203/javascript-how-to-simulate-change-event-in-internet-explorer-delegation)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
choicefile.onchange = function() {alert("test");};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Something particular with IE is, if you put higher security level, you need to **allow scripts and activeX** content when you load the website.

Answer (score 0):

try 
   onclick="javascript:alert('test');"
instead of onchange.
Old ie versions and compatibility modes don't support onchange very well.