# Javascript show div on HTML select

Tags: javascript

I've been playing with javascript to create a drop down list that shows a div depending on which option is selected.

All the code can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nmdTy/

```
var select = document.getElementById('test'),
onChange = function(event) {
    var shown = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 1;
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = shown ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

I want to know how do I streamline this code and remove repetition - maybe some kind of loop?

Comment: What do you mean by removing the repetition ?

Comment: @dreamweiver did you click the fiddle?

Comment: you can  improvise your code still more ,more of it being redundant.write a single handler, based on the value either 1 or 2 set the style .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two event handlers, you can use variables (shown below) to determine which `div` needs to be displayed or hidden.

```
var select = document.getElementById('test'), onChange = function(event) {
    var div1 = 'hidden_div';
    var div2 = 'hidden_div2';

    var index1 = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 1;
    var index2 = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 2;

    if(index1 || index2){
        document.getElementById(div1).style.display = index1 ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById(div2).style.display = index2 ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(div1).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(div2).style.display = 'none';
    }
};

// attach event handler
if (window.addEventListener) {
    select.addEventListener('change', onChange, false);
} else {
    // of course, IE < 9 needs special treatment
    select.attachEvent('onchange', function() {
        onChange.apply(select, arguments);
    });
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmdTy/15/)

Comment: You still keep some repetition.

Comment: @TomášZato Which repetition are you referring to? Did I look something over?

Comment: Of course, the OP did not define what does he mean by repetition, but I don't really like the idea of writing too many `if` statements. It's just my opinion.

Comment: @TomášZato See my latest edit I've improved the function dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

Another code :

```
var select = document.getElementById('test'),
    nbItems = 2,
    onChange = function (event) {
        var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

        for (var i = 1; i <= nbItems; i++) {
            document.getElementById('hidden_div' + i).style.display = val == i ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmdTy/11/

Comment: This is what I would do while solving real-life problem.

Comment: this is very simple yet very elegant at the same time, I really like it and its just the kind of thing I was after. But where would this leave me say if the divs 'hidden_div1/2' had a different names say something like 'some_div' and 'this_other_div'?

Comment: @twigg you can use an array (like Tomáš Zato has done in his solution) in order to match the divs... See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nmdTy/17/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what do you mean by "*repetition*" but my guess is, that you don't want to type every each of the `div`s to be hidden/shown.
There could be multiple approaches to such task. The most universal is to have the `div` id's in a separate array. Then you can hide all but the selected div.

```
var divs = ["hidden_div1", "special_hidden", "one_more_hidden"];  
var select = document.getElementById('test');
var onchange = function(event) {   //Use var!
    var shown = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    for(var i=0; i<window.divs.length; i++) {   //It would be more effective to save last shown div in a variable, but I've chosen this aproach with loop
        var div = document.getElementById(window.divs[i]);
        if(div!=null) {
          if(i==shown)  
            div.style.display="block";
          else
            div.style.display="none";
        }
    }
};
select.addEventListener("change", onchange);  //Could type the function right here, without using "onchange" variable
```

In my code, `<option>` value represents index in the array. Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/KpdPx/).

Answer (score 0):

Delegating a change event in IE<9 is a pain. It is possible, [check this question to see how it's done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331203/javascript-how-to-simulate-change-event-in-internet-explorer-delegation), but it's not what you call elegant.

But your code doesn't delegate the event, so just attaching the handler directly at the `onload` event should do the trick (and it's X-browser compatible):

```
document.getElementById('test').onchange = function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;//the only IE headache
    var shown = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 1;
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = shown ? 'block' : 'none';
    //^^ could keep a reference to this in a closure
};
```

The full code (with `onload` and closure reference to hidden div *and* [preventing memory leaks in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186750/memory-leak-risk-in-javascript-closures)) should look like this:

```
var winLoad = function(e)
{
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('hidden_div');
    document.getElementById('test').onchange = function(e)
    {
        var shown = !!(this.option[this.selectedIndex].value == 1);//to be safe, coerce to bool
        hiddenDiv.style.display = shown ? 'block' : 'none';
    };
    if (window.addEventListener)
    {
        return window.removeEventListener('load',winLoad,false);
    }
    return window.detachEvent('onload',winLoad);
};
if (window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener('load',winLoad,false);
}
else
{
    window.attachEvent('onload',winLoad);
}
```

that should work fine on all major browsers, even IE7 (probably IE6, too)