# Onchange event for Html-form-elements in td tag with Chrome

Tags: javascript, forms, function, google-chrome, onchange

How to call an onchange event in a table cell (td) for a form tag in it with Chrome?
The following code works for me for all browsers except for chrome. Surprising it works with Opera 15 (should use the same engine (webkit/blink) like the newest Google Chrome).

```
<table><tr>
    <td onchange="bla()">
        <select>
            <option value="n">foo</option>
            <option value="n">foo</option>
            <option value="n">foo</option>
            <option value="n">foo</option>
            <option value="n">foo</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td onchange="bla()">
        <input type="text" />
    </td>

    <td>
    </td>
</tr></table>



<script>
function bla() {
    alert('something changed...');
}
</script>
```

I know it is possible to bind the event to the select tag but for my web-application it won't work that well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason *why* the `onchange` doesn't work as it should is because it's not the *cell* that changes, it's the form element inside. Sure, if you click on a tables contents, the table is clicked, too. That makes sense: you can't open a door *inside* a house without opening the front door first.
You can, however, go inside a room, cut your hair (fire a change-event on yourself) without changing the room where this event took place. In that respect, it makes sense the change event doesn't fire on the parent cell.

The event *does* traverse the DOM, though, and it *does* pass the table cell, so you *can* pick it up there, but not with HTML attributes. (BTW: try to use those as little as possible).

Try binding a listener to the entire table in JS. That way, there's only 1 listener that works for all events (it's called event delegation):

```
//assume tbl has id foobar:
document.getElementById('foobar').addEventListener('change',function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var name = target.id || target.getAttribute('name');
    alert('the ' + name + ' element changed!');
},false);
```

[Here's a slightly more complex version of event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331203/javascript-how-to-simulate-change-event-in-internet-explorer-delegation), which also deals with change events on select elements in IE8. (the change event doesn't bubble in old IE's).

A couple of links:

- As always: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener)
- An article on [How delegation works](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/), and how easy it really is
- And good ol' quirksmode: [a comprehensive overview on event order/event models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Comment: Because this worked in all the other browsers I tested, I thought it's a Chrome bug so I was searching for a workaround. But sure. All you said makes sense.Normally I wouldn't use an event on a different tag then the one that should fire it.

Comment: @Werner: Well, I'm actually suggesting you _do_ listen for an ecent on a different tag, in your case, you could use _either_ the form, or `document.body`, or even `window`... if your contents is dynamically generated, that's the only way to ensure the events are handled correctly.