# Event listener for TD content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to have a function triggered when anything changes on a table. I have an event listener and it works perfectly if anything changes in the table, except simple text in `<td>`. I need the event listener (or anything else) to capture changes in the following structure:

```
<td id="x">Text</td>
```

Please find below the full code that I use. I need the alert to be displayed when anything on the last row of the table changes (last  - IDs "2,0" and "2,1"). The "Change Text" button changes the text in the s that I am interested of capturing the events of.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="foobar">
  <tr>
    <td id="aaa" name="YYY">
        <select name="001" id="0,0">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    <td id="bbb" name="XXX"><input name="CCC" id="0,1" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="CCC2" id="1,0" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="CCC3" ud="1,1" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="2,0" name="abc">TEST 1</td>
    <td><div id="2,1">TEST 2</div> </td>
    </tr>

    <br><br>
</table>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>


<script>
function changeText(){
    var x=Math.random(100);
    document.getElementById('2,1').innerHTML = x;
}


document.getElementById('foobar').addEventListener('change',function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var name = target.id || target.getAttribute('name');
    alert('the ' + name + ' element changed!');
},false);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please read you question again? I have an event listener and it works perfectly if anything changes in the table, except simple text in (huh???).

Comment: jsquery does not "watch" your elements, it notices when you "bind" the actions with a function, so you need to notice any possible actions that can be done to one.

Comment: hi Daniel. I meant "simple text in a <td>". The following part will change:
`<td><div id="2,1">TEST 2</div> </td>`

the Button I use changes that text to something using the following:
`document.getElementById('2,1').innerHTML = x;`

Yet the event lisner doesn't identify this change.

Comment: when this changes, the event listener identifies the change:
`<td id="bbb" name="XXX"><input name="CCC" id="0,1" type="text"></td>`. Also when this changes, it gets identified: `<select name="001" id="0,0">`. However, when this changes, I get nothing:
`<td id="2,0" name="abc">TEST 1</td>`